# Reg Ex Numerical Range

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will let me put in a value between 0-5,000. I am a novice and fairly new to regular expressions. `^(0?[0-4]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])$` is what I have so far but it will only allow me to go to 4,999. Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please also mention which programming language you are using to work on this regular expression.

Comment: Some context as to what language you're using would certainly be helpful. If you're in the right language/platform you could solve this by using a control that's meant for actual numerical values and setting max/min on the control itself rather than using a regex.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you parse this part of the string as a number and compare it to 5000, outside of a regex? If you use regex for this, I bet whoever is going to read your code will hate you fiercely!

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use a regex for a numerical range validation. Use regex to ensure that a string matches a *pattern* (ie. consists of only digits), but then just convert the string to a number and validate that number.

Regexes are not golden hammers, and there are only so many nails they can be used on effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Follow Ilya Kogan's answer.

If you really want you can do:

```
(5000|[1234]?\d{3})(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
println '3,1777' ==~ /[0-4]((\,)\d{1,3})?/
println '3,999' ==~ /[0-4]((\,)\d{1,3})?/
```

That's for Groovy. Still, you can use regex in any language supporting PCRE =)

Answer (score 0):

`^(5000|[1-4][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])$`